# css - move text to right

Tags: css, html

This is something that annoys me very often.
If you create a `<div>` and style the border (for example, `border-radius: 3px;`) the text is almost on top of the border, which looks very bad.
The only solution I could come up with was wrapping the contents of that div in another div, and move the wrapping div ±3px to the right.
This creates a lot extra mark-up, and it somehow doesn't feel right, as if there is a bettr solution.

So here's my question:
**Is it possible to move the contents of a div three pixels to the right as described above with css-only?**

Of course I'd like a cross-browser solution, but I don't mind 1 css rule per browser, I can throw that somewhere at the bottom of my stylesheet and never look at it again, that won't complicate the markup.

Comment: Can u provide your code or a fiddle?

Comment: @Sowmya there is no code, so what should I put in a jsFiddle? Well, I could give you this: <div style="border-radius:3px;">hgfndhscvdhjskcgnsaxjkncjknaxka.mnckhsgnjkamjxkacnn<BR />fhfeufcijsfhkscklssdklchkxjkdjlnfldjkszjaacgkdhklchgjrklcmx</div>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
padding-left:3px;
```

Add that to your div which has the text in it.

Read more about padding: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Answer (score 3):

Easy, you can either use `padding: 0 3px;` (horizontal padding only), `padding-left: 3px;`..

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/D3BSL/4/

Comment: Yeah, it does. How could I fully forget that? Lack of coffee, that's how!

Answer (score -2):

i hope you are looking like this :- http://tinkerbin.com/q4cVJ0FF

**HTML**

```
<div>stack</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
background:red;
border-radius:3px;
    padding-left:3px;
}
```

you can easily get your desired through `padding` and you can adjust the padding from all four sides `left,right,top,bottom`...