# CSS - heading logo

Tags: html, css, layout

I am making a webpage with HTML and CSS. My problem is that the heading is appearing on top of the small logo I have inserted towards the left. I want to move the heading by some distance towards the right away from the logo. How can I do this?

```
h1 { 
    font-family: "Arial" ; 
    color: #808080; 
    font-size:190%;
} 

h1 { 
    background-image: url(something.png); 
    background-size: 20px 20px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: left ; 
    padding:1px; 
    margin:-2px; 
}
```

Comment: Put what you have done so far, please.

Comment: Please post both relevant HTML and CSS.  We can't possibly guess what you've coded to get where you are.

Comment: h1 {
  font-family: "Arial" ;
  color: #808080;
font-size:190%;


    
   
    
}

h1 { background-image: url(something.png); 
background-size: 20px 20px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left  ; 

padding:1px;
margin:-2px;
}

Comment: not allowed to post html code here due to some reasons..may problem is  The heading is on the small logo...logo is towards the left..I want to move the heading towards right away from logo by few distance..any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Just Edit your Question again and post the code there...

Comment: Your code makes no sense. I think it's better to use a 'ID' or even a 'CLASS'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css - move text to right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244525/css-move-text-to-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying the following style properties to the header, I have come up with a simple solution:

```css
header {
    display: block;
    line-height: 4em;
    height: 120px;
    padding-left: 120px;
    background: #4466FF url('http://placehold.it/80x80/FFFFFF/444466&text=My+Logo') no-repeat 20px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

First, I made the `<header>` a `block` element. If this is a `<div>` then you do not need to set the `display` property. Next, I determined the size and weight of the text. This is vital when determining the line-height *(pseudo-vertical-align)*. After adding the background image and setting its offset, I then added `left-padding` to the `<header>` to offset it 20px to the right of the background logo.

This is the result:

[image]

Here is a <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eV3LP/2/)</kbd> for the above layout.

```html
<header>My Header</header>
<content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
<footer>Copyright 2014</footer>
```

```css
body {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    display: block;
    line-height: 4em;
    height: 120px;
    padding-left: 120px;
    background: #4466FF url('http://placehold.it/80x80/FFFFFF/444466&text=My+Logo') no-repeat 20px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
}

content {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    background: #AAAABB;
    padding: 4px;
}

footer {
    display: block;
    line-height: 4em;
    height: 60px;
    background: #223377;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..it perfectly works...can you also tell me how to put the whole web page in the center? there will be a body in the background

Comment: You mean? `body { margin: 0 auto; }`? I updated my code/demo.

Comment: yes . Also some of the images are not visible on the webpage when I run it. What could be the reason?

Comment: Invalid path possibly. Try to right-click on the image placeholder and open it in a new window to check the path.